# Internet Explorer Scaling not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have a map created with d3. I set it to have the width of the parent div (with id map) and height with a ratio of 5/9 to to the width. The viewBox has been set to "0 0 width height".

Here is the setup:

```
var width = $("#map").width(),
    height = width * 500 / 900,
    active = d3.select(null);


var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);


var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);


projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)

g = svg.append("g");
```

Here is how it looks like in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

But it looks like this in IE:

[image: IE]

The scaling is completely messed up. I believe it has to do with the viewBox. Could someone explain how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you change `.attr('width', '100%')` to `.attr('width', width)` and do the same for the height? Is the scaling still different?

Comment: Perect! This solution made it work for nearly every browser. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that `height: "100%"` is handled differently by Chrome and IE. You have smartly set your `height` variable to be based on your `width` and aspect ratio, but to take advantage of this, you'll need to use these values when setting the dimensions of your svg as well as the `viewBox`:

```
var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
```

Comment: This worked, but a new problem arises from this. The reason I used the 100% was to make the map responsive, so the map scaled perfectly as I resized the browser. Now, it will be at the correct scale on load, but won't resize as I change the dimensions of the browser. How do I fix this new problem?

Comment: set the div `#map` to width 100% in your css. Then use `d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {...})`. Inside that function, recalculate the `width` of `#map` and get the `height` from that as you did earlier in your code. Then call `svg.attr('width', width).attr('height',  height)` again to set the new values.

Comment: Also, if you do this, be sure to set `.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')` and don't update the `viewBox` on resize, only the `width` and `height`.